# Not able to convert String into Integer using parseInt() in java

Tags: java, parseint

I have a string, that I want to first split and then convert into integer. 
Here is my code :

```
String Table_data = "$452";          
String[] words=Table_data.split("\\$");
for(String w:words)
{
    int result = Integer.parseInt(w);
    System.out.print(result);
}
```

I have not much experience in java.
I tried but its shows some error like `"java.lang.NumberFormatException".`

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: By splitting on `$`, your words array looks like this: `["", "452"]` and you are getting the exception due to the blank string.

Comment: can you please provide solution code. thanks

Comment: Thanks @sisanared
it's work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want is:

```
String Table_data = "$452";  
int result = Integer.parseInt(Table_data.replace("$", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like this way. I have used substring instead of split.

```
    String Table_data = "$452";
    String s=Table_data.substring(1);
    int result=Integer.parseInt(s);
    System.out.println(result);
```